Can only a bramha jnani and knower of 4 Vedas be called a Guru?
Bhagavatam says-
tasmād guruṁ prapadyeta jijñāsuḥ śreya uttamam
śābde pare ca niṣṇātaṁ brahmaṇy upaśamāśrayam
‘Therefore, one desirous of knowing the ultimate welfare should approach a preceptor who is well versed in the Vedas, who has realized the Absolute Reality, and who has thus become the abode of peace.’ (SB 11.3.21)”
What do scriptures say about this?

I am posting a discussion on the quality of a Guru given in Linga Purana. Only that person who has a decisive knowledge of the Atman can be a Guru. Knowledge of scripture without direct experience of the Atman will not be of much use.
Quality of a Guru

The preceptor who is conversant with the scriptural texts, who is
intelligent, who is favorably disposed towards common people, who
performs penance, who is engaged in following accepted worldly
conventions and who knows the principles is known as one who bestows
salvation.
He may be endowed with all characteristic qualities; he may be an
expert in all sacred texts, and he may be conversant with all means
and modes, but if he is devoid of the real truth, all the other
qualities shall be futile to him.
If he has no decisive knowledge of the Atman which is self-evident
great principle, he is not blessed himself. How can he bless others?
The brahmin who is enlightened is pure and is capable of accomplishing
things. But whence can there be enlightenment in one who is devoid of
principles? Whence can there be comprehension of self? …………… Hence,
those liberated souls who are conversant with the principles
(realities) can redeem others. The principle that produces perfect
cognition originates from his greatest bliss.
Only he who has understood the truth can be a guide unto bliss and not
one who is a preceptor only in name but who is devoid of cognition.
Such people cannot redeem one another. Can a rock redeem another rock?
Those who have perfect cognition only in name can have salvation only
in name.
Command that causes the destruction of bonds is instantaneously born
by the sight and touch of the yogins or even by conversing with them.
Or, the preceptor may enter the physical body of the disciple by the
yogic path and enlighten him by means of the yogic power after
understanding all the entities.

Linga Purana II.20.34-43

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/60222/what-is-the-punishment-for-lusting-on-female-relatives please answer this question sir

Paraskara Grihya Sutra 2.5 (Upanayanam)


Let him live forty-eight years as a student for the (four) Vedas,




Or twelve years for each Veda,




Or until he has learnt it.




If he behaves thus, his fame when he has become a Snātaka (i.e. when he has taken the bath at the end of his studentship) will be (such that people will say of him), 'To-day he stays there; to-day he stays there.'




There are three (kinds of) Snātakas: a Vidyā-snātaka (i.e. a Snātaka by knowledge), a Vrata-snātaka (i.e. a Snātaka by the completion of his vows), and a Vidyā-vrata-snātaka (i.e. a Snātaka both by knowledge and by the completion of his vows).




He who performs the Samāvartana ceremony, after having finished the study of the Veda, but before the time of his vows has expired, is a Vidyā-snātaka.


A snataka later becomes a Guru. As you can see you can study four Vedas or one Veda. So it is not mandatory to study all four vedas. One Veda is also fine.

Thanks Sir..one may learn any number of vedas as one is capable.And does becoming a snataka imply one is authorised to become a Guru?.but my question is can only a person learned in all 4 vedas and is a jnani may become a guru?And who is the author of this Grihyasutra? Is this work a post vedic one? Then it has no authority.

@Harsh When someone has Upanayanam and learned Veda, later he only can become Guru. Without learning Veda, how can one become a Guru? The process of learning Veda is initiated by Upanayanam and completed by becoming Snataka. Now, the rule of becoming Snataka, I explained, which says one Veda will do.

Does becoming a Snataka imply one is fit to be a Guru?Just like becoming a post graduate does not mean one is a lecturer

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/60222/what-is-the-punishment-for-lusting-on-female-relatives  please answer this question sir

@Harsh don't know the answer.

Your quoted original Sanskrit shloka didn't mention Veda explicitly. So it's not mandatory in outward sense of learning.
It seems to be added by the translator as commentary.
Translator insertions without using brackets is very common these days, so you have to develop a basic grip on sanskrit.
