What is the punishment for lusting on female relatives?
What is the punishment for a lusting on female relatives especially father's sister in smritis and itiHasas?
Please dont use chatgpt or ai as i am not finding even one verse mentioned in ai in actual books..please help me..
I am looking for verses which describe penance and punishment..

Are you looking for prayaschitta? The mind can be cleansed from any sin only by daily meditation (for long hours for faster purification).

No Sir manu smriti says such a person should be killed hence i want to know if there are any other smritis that give any other atonement

See if this helps: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19133/34973

Which verse from manusmriti? can you please tell me?

@Hari Hara sir I am asking about lustful thoughts not actual intercourse

@Amritendu Mukhyopadhyay sir - Manu Smriti (11.174):
पितृव्यां मातुलं चैव यः कामयेत भार्यया |
स वध्यः पापकरो नात्र कार्या विचार्यते ||
Pitr̥vyāṃ mātulaṃ caiva yaḥ kāmayet bhāryayā |
Sa vadhyaḥ pāpakaro nātra kāryā vicāryate ||
Translation: "He who lusts after his father's sister or mother's sister is a sinner and shall be killed, no consideration is necessary." I dont know if this is an authentic verse

This is not authentic verse. 11.174. A man who has committed a bestial crime, or an unnatural crime with a female, or has had intercourse in water, or with a menstruating woman, shall perform a Samtapana Krikkhra.

11.172. He who has approached the daughter of his father's sister, (who is almost equal to) a sister, (the daughter) of his mother's sister, or of his mother's full brother, shall perform a lunar penance.

You can read check the Manusmriti here. https://saraswat-prakashan.weebly.com/manusmriti.html

In Smriti shastra, there is always some prayschitta for sins. So from your verse it was very clear someone fabricated it. It is fake.

There is no punishment for bad thoughts. Sin only accrues to sinful deeds and not thoughts. Think of a chess game. You may be calculating long sequences of moves. Those thoughts will not matter. Only actual movement of pieces will be officially considered.

Parikshit, who was like a honey-bee in grasping the essential good in
everything, abstained from killing Kali, because there is one great
excellence pertaining to his age – whatever good you do fructifies
immediately, but not so the evil deeds; and besides, in Kali’s age sin
accrues only to sinful deeds and not to sinful thoughts. Kali is like
one who is cowardly before the brave, but brave before the cowardly.
He holds no fear for the good, but like a wolf he is always vigilant
and alert to pounce upon those who are thoughtless and unobservant.

Srimad Bhagavata Purana translated by Swami Tapasyananda I.18.7
I checked the on line translation given in vedabase after reading the comment.
ŚB 1.18.7

नानुद्वेष्टि कलिं सम्राट् सारङ्ग इव सारभुक् । कुशलान्याशु सिद्ध्यन्ति
नेतराणि कृतानि यत् ॥ ७ ॥ nānudveṣṭi kaliṁ samrāṭ sāraṅga iva sāra-bhuk
kuśalāny āśu siddhyanti netarāṇi kṛtāni yat

Synonyms
na — never; anudveṣṭi — envious; kalim — unto the personality of Kali; samrāṭ — the Emperor; sāram-ga — realist, like the bees; iva — like; sāra-bhuk — one who accepts the substance; kuśalāni — auspicious objects; āśu — immediately; siddhyanti — become successful; na — never; itarāṇi — which are inauspicious; kṛtāni — being performed; yat — as much as.
Translation

Mahārāja Parīkṣit was a realist, like the bees who only accept the
essence [of a flower]. He knew perfectly well that in this Age of
Kali, auspicious things produce good effects immediately, whereas
inauspicious acts must be actually performed [to render effects]. So
he was never envious of the personality of Kali.

Vedabase translation (https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/18/7/)
It also says that bad acts must be actually performed to be effective. The implication is that sinful thoughts do not lead to sin.

The Bhagavatam sanskrit shloka does not mention that sinful thoughts are not sin..Please quote some other source..thanks

Thanks sir please quote some more verses and sources

Isnt lusting itself an act?

Read the purport in the vedabase link provided above please. Also related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34037/is-it-a-mental-sin-to-think-of-killing-other-people-or-fantasize-about-killing

I don't know of other sources. Some additional sources are given in the question mentioned in another comment. Just lusting is not an act.
